# Number of connective orbit types of torus actions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Suppose that topological group $G$ acting on topological space $X$. If the
set $\left\{ \left[ G_{x}\right] :x\in X\right\} $ is finite, where $\left[
G_{x}\right] $ denotes the conjugacy class of the isotropy subgroup $G_{x}$
in $G$, then the group $G$ is said to act on a space $X$ with finitely many
orbit types (FMOT). If the set $\left\{ \left[ \left( G_{x}\right) _{0}%
\right] :x\in X\right\} $ is finite, where $\left( G_{x}\right) _{0}$
denotes the identity component of the isotropy subgroup $G_{x}$ in $G$, then
the group $G$ is said to act on a space $X$ with finitely many connective
orbit types (FMCOT).

I asked before that [Fixed point set for a subcircle of torus actions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235984/fixed-point-set-for-a-subcircle-of-torus-actions) if $T$ is a torus and $X$ is a $T$-space with finitely
many connective orbit type, then there is a subcircle $L=\mathbb{S}%
^{1}\subset T$ such that $X^{L}=X^{T}$ (fixed point sets of the action). I
couldn't get a complete answer to this question.

While I was thinking about this question, I came across something like this:
Closed subgroups of torus $T=\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times
\cdots \times \mathbb{S}^{1}$ has type $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}%
^{1}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{n_{1}}\times 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{n_{2}}\times \cdots \times 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{n_{k}}$. So connected closed subgroups of $T$ has type $\mathbb{S}%
^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \left\{
1\right\} \times \left\{ 1\right\} \times \cdots \times \left\{ 1\right\} $.
Isn't there already finite number of connective orbit types for torus
actions on any topological space? Where am i doing wrong?

**Add:** I find this thesis ''Computation of Fixed Point Data from Equivariant Cohomology by Courtney K. Taylor''

[image]

Comment: No there are infinitely many non-cconjugate subgroups of the same type. The crucial point here is the difference between inner and non-inner automorphism.
For example, for any two embeddings $f_1,f_2:S^1\to T^2$ there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $T^2$  such that $f_2=\sigma\circ f_1$.
However there need not be an inner automorphsm.

Comment: @HenrikRüping Since $T$ is abelian, the conjugacy class $[(G_x)_0]$ consists of only $(G_x)_0$. So $(G_x)_0$ equals to  $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \left\{1\right\} \times \left\{ 1\right\} \times \cdots \times \left\{ 1\right\}$?

Comment: @HenrikRüping For any $x \in X$, $G_x=\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_{1}}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_{2}}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_{k}}$?

Comment: Well maybe we should have a closer look at the example of $T^2$. Then any closed subgroup of $T^2$ is either trivial, the whole of $T^2$ or of the form $\{(at,bt)\mid t\in S^1\}$ for some coprime $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$.
They are all nonconjugate and they are all "of the type" $S^1\times \{1\}$. The map that assigns to a conjugacy class of a closed subgroup its type thus sends infinitely many different conjugacy classes to the same type.

Comment: @HenrikRüping Thank you for your time and patient reply.

Comment: @HenrikRüping What is the meaning of coprime $a,b$, as in the picture I added above? If they are not coprime, then $\{(at,bt)\mid t\in S^1\}$ is not a subgroup?